# Is there any way to set a CSS min-width on an element that is floated?

Tags: html, css-float, css

I have this html:

```
<div id="subNav"></div>
<div id="feed"></div>
<div id="feedBar"></div>
```

I have floated all of these divs left. I set the width of `#subNav` and `#feedBar`, but on `#feed` I set its min-width . It takes the min-width even though the window is larger. Is there any way that with floating you can make the min-width work? I am trying to make a flexible layout on the page.

Comment: A floated element will collapse to the size of its contents, or the `width`, `min-width` or `max-width` (whichever's defined).

Comment: @David Is there any way to override this behavior? with javascript?

Comment: yeah. Of course. You'll need to define what you want the width to be, though. In terms of the screen, or its parent element? Also: can you define what you mean by 'make the `min-width` work'?

Comment: You could certainly use JavaScript to set the width of #feed to the window width minus the widths of #subNav and #feedBar. Then you'd also want to set a resize handler on the window to re-set #feed's width as necessary. But there are lots of different ways to approach this, many of which would not require JavaScript. Google "3-column layout with liquid center" and find one that makes sense to you and is easy to integrate with what you've got so far.

Comment: @David What I mean by "make the `min-width` work" is make it so that when the window is adjusted the feed fills the in between space. I want the width to be at least 500px and the screen. The width of `#subNav` and `#feedBar` are 175px and 250px respectively.

Answer (score 2):

The following answer uses a **JavaScript** solution, in response to @Chromedude's comment (to the original question):

> @David Is there any way to override this behavior? with javascript?

I'm sure there's a far more simple way of doing this (certainly with a JavaScript library), but this was the best I could come up with at this time of morning (in the UK):

```
var feed = document.getElementById('feed');
var width = document.width;
var feedBarWidth = document.getElementById('feedBar').clientWidth;
var subNavWidth = document.getElementById('subNav').clientWidth;
feed.setAttribute('style', 'width: ' + (width - (subNavWidth + feedBarWidth)) + 'px');
```

[JS Fiddle demo](http://jsfiddle.net/davidThomas/PW9rD/).

Using jQuery (just as a suggestion as to the ease offered by a library):

```
var bodyWidth = $(document).width();
var subNavWidth = $('#subNav').width();
var feedBarWidth = $('#feedBar').width();
$('#feed').css('width', bodyWidth - (subNavWidth + feedBarWidth));
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a grid system such as the one in [Foundation 3](http://foundation.zurb.com/docs/grid.php). When placed on a `div` representing an element of the grid, `min-width` behaves just fine.

To get `min-width` to work without a grid, use a CSS rule that inserts an invisible pseudo-element with the desired minimum paragraph width.

```
p:before {
  content: "";
  width: 10em;
  display: block;
  overflow: hidden;
}
```

Further details are at the [source](http://css-tricks.com/minimum-paragraph-widths/) where I learned this.